# Can I assign HTML values in MVC view using Html Helpers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is this right? I am trying to display value in input box dynamically?

can anyone advice me is this corect approach? but still I am getting here only + + in input box?

Comment: 62% isn't too bad - OP's unaccepted questions are all relatively recent. But point stands @kumar, please accept some of your other answers if possible. If you haven't got an acceptable answer try editing your question, this will bump it up the lists.

Comment: Hello David.. Thanks please check my previous post I am answering the question wchih the people helping me out.. lot..I am very thankfull to those guys who are helping me... check it out my post which I answered..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Html.DisplayFor` will render a label in this case. If you want to write in this way just use `<%= Model.Date.ToString() %>` for the value attribute of the input.

**These HTML helpers will render the markup for you, don't try and use them as methods to return data. You can get the data by just using `<%=Model.MyProperty%>` as long as it is a strongy-typed view.**

Try just using `<%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date) %>`

OR

`<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date) %>` (the EditorFor will automatically render a textbox anyway)

OR

`<%= Html.TextBox("Date", Model.Date) %>` (this is not a strongly-typed helper, you're doing the data binding yourself with the second argument)

Comment: In that case just use a Html.TextBox - if it's input then you won't be binding to any data. If it's editing then use Html.TextBoxFor or Html.TextBox("Date",Model.Date.ToString()).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do you want this?

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="Date-<%=Model.ID%>" 
  value= " <%= "+" + Model.Date.ToString() + "+" %>"  />
```

I don't know what **Model** is for you, but something like this might help you, if it is an object of a class that has some property Date.